# Why doesn't the following jQuery code disable the submit button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to disable the submit button on the form when username, email or password fields or all of them are empty and user fills all of then I am enabling the submit button, but the following code doesn't it doesn't disable the submit button.

**html code:**

```
    <form id="new_user_form">
                                        {% csrf_token %}
                                     <div class="modal-content" data-method="post" id="modalform" >
                                           <div class="modal-header">
                                               <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                               <h4 class="modal-title">Sign Up</h4>
                                           </div>
                                        <div onload="validateForm();" class="modal-body">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="usr">Username:</label>
                                                <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control input-sm" id="username">
                                                <label for="eml">Email:</label>
                                                <input type="email" name="emil" class="form-control input-sm" id="emailid">
                                                <label for="passwordd">Password:</label>
                                                <input onchange="checkPasswordMatch();" type="password" name="password" class="form-control input-sm" id="password">
                                                <label for="passwordd">Retype Password:</label>
                                                <input type="password" name="retrypassword" class="form-control input-sm" id="retrypassword">
                                                <br/><div style="color:blue;" id="doesPasswordMatch">  </div>
                                                <span class="help-block">Ensure, You Choose Correct Profession...</span>

                                        <label for="inputfile">Upload Profile Picture</label>
                                       <input type="file" id="inputfile">
                                       <p class="help-block">The Profile Picture help people to identify you.</p>
                                            </div role="Form group">
                                          </div role="modal-dialog">
                        <!--Closing Of Sign Up Modal Page -->
                                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="submit" onclose="showSuccessMessage();">Submit</button>
                                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                                </div role="modal-footer">
                                    </div role="modal content">
```

**jquery code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkPasswordMatch() {
        if ($('#password').val() == $('#retrypassword').val())
            $('#doesPasswordMatch').html("<h4>  Match </h4>").css('color', 'rgb(34,139,34)');
        else
            $('#doesPasswordMatch').html("<h4>  Does not match </h4>").css('color', 'rgb(128,0,0)');

    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#submit').attr('disable', true);
        $('#retrypassword').keyup(checkPasswordMatch);
        if ($('#username').val() == '' || $('#email').val() == '' || $('#password').val() == '')
            $('#submit').attr('disable', false);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: you should use `prop` instead of `attr`

Comment: @Musa: Quite true, although `attr` will work because jQuery fixes it up for you.

Comment: and it's disabled not disable

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I think they stopped doing that from 1.6

Comment: @Musa: No. 1.6 stopped doing it **very briefly** when `prop` was added. It was a complete disaster and very, very quickly (most of) the old behavior was put back (including handling `disabled`, `selected`, and `checked`). Even 3.x still does it: https://jsfiddle.net/4rvt47gL/

Answer (score 3):

The property is `disabled` (with a `d` at the end), not `disable`. And although [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr) will handle this for you for historic reasons, the correct way to set it is via [`prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop):

```
$("#submit").prop("disabled", true);
// ----------^^^^---------^
```

Comment: @Ahtisham: If it still doesn't work, there's *another* problem with the code. This is the obvious one (well, two) that jumped out. Use your debugger to step through the code, inspect variables, etc., etc.

Answer (score 1):

It should be `disabled` and NOT `disable`

This should work:

```
$('#submit').attr('disabled',true);
```

or

```
$('#submit').attr("disabled","disabled");
```